# Mount disks at startup

Tags: mount

I want to mount my drive just after I login. I followed an answer on stackoverflow. It asks to create a script in `/etc/profile.d` directory. I am pasting content of the file here

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/udisks --mount /dev/sda3
```

These commands mount my drive at `/media/<name of the drive>`. When I do `cd /media/Media`, I get `permission denied`. I want to mount the drive at `/media/<username>/<name of the drive>` just as when I mount drives manually using GUI.

Comment: if you want your partition to be mounted on startup, then create a new entry on `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: This is not working because it is mounting the disk as `root`. (Surely there is a root bash shell started before you log in, and this one will mount the disk). The solution of @rusty should work.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create the script (like in your `$HOME` directory under the directory `bin`);

   ```
   mkdir $HOME/bin
   touch $HOME/bin/mountSDA6.sh
   chmod +x $HOME/bin/mountSDA6.sh
   nano $HOME/bin/mountSDA6.sh
   ```

   and add the script contents, say:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   /usr/bin/udisks --mount /dev/sda6
   /usr/bin/udisks --mount /dev/sda3
   ```

   or other partitions which you need to, and save it and close.
2. Start ***Startup Applications*** (search in Dash or select from the gear-menu on top unity panel), click **Add** and in the *Add Startup Program* window fill the required fields. (In the *Command* field specify the full path of the script, but here simply using *mountSDA6.sh* should work as it's created in your `$HOME/bin` directory. Or you instead of creating script, just use the command to mount here in the *Command* field.) Click on **Add** and you're done. On next log-on the partitions should be mounted.

   [image: snap1]

---

**Alternatively**, you can edit `/etc/fstab` file where you can have more control over your mounts by specifying various different mount options.

Comment: I have tried this method. Is it possible to specify mount point in the command. I want to mount the partition at `/media/username/paritionName`. Command specified above mounts the partition at `/media/partitionName`.

Comment: @Neeraj you should create an entry in the `/etc/fstab` file. Please edit you question to attach the output of `sudo fdisk -l`

Comment: I used `udisksctl mount --block-device /dev/disk/by-uuid/<uuid>` and it's fulfilling all my requirements. I found it on [Ubuntu Help page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticallyMountPartitions). Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, `udisksctl mount` is the correct answer.

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
sudo mkdir -p /media/<username>/<name of drive>
```

to create the path. Then open the /etc/fstab with

```
sudo <text editor(nano, leafpad...)> /etc/fstab
```

and add

```
/dev/sda3 /media/<username>/<name of drive> <file system type (ext4, ntfs...)> defaults 0 0
```

to the end. Type then

```
sudo mount -a
```

to validate /etc/fstab immediately.

For more information read [this](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/7.1/chapter08/fstab.html) (Creating the /etc/fstab File)

Comment: ...and this will mount the disk as root giving exactly the same error as in the original question. Moreover, creating the directory by hand and as root, it will make all future automatic mounting of external disks failing. Have you tested it?

Comment: If you want to create a directory in the /media folder, you have to be root or a sudoer, in the opposite you dont have the permission to do anything. If you ask did it worked for me - yes. Everytime I have the need to mount something by booting, I do it through the fstab file, doesn't matter is it a ntfs partition or a network location. I don't know what exactly you want to mount and I gave you just a example, you could easily create a directory in your home folder and mount it there. I am mounting 2 network locations in my homefolder :S

Comment: `udiskctl mount --block-device /dev/sda3` works as user. It sends a message to DBus which will mount the disk and then change the directory permissions so that the user can access it. You are not supposed to touch the `/media` directory yourself... otherwise you should take care of the permission and, if mounting a filesystem that do not understand unix semantics, pass the appropriate `-o user=...,group=...` options to `mount` (and putting that in the `fstab`, too).

Comment: OK, I'm still learning and I appreciate every advice ;)